# When is there a charge for sending/recieving BitCoins and other CryptoCurrencies

Tags: bitcoin-core

I want to transfer BitCoins from my local wallet (to a new wallet) and then 'extract' the BitCoin Cash to a different new wallet.  Will I incur a charge?

Comment: Can you clarify more precisely what it is you're trying to do? Do you understand that transferring bitcoins from one wallet to another will leave the bitcoin cash associated with those bitcoins (if there was any) still in the same place it always was. What wallet are you currently using? What's the purpose of transferring the bitcoins?

Comment: As David Schwartz said. After the fork, transactions only effect one of the two bitcoin block chains, btc or btc cash but not both. That said for btc you probably may need to pay fee when sending btc. Not receiving. So try to consolidate transactions.

Comment: My wallet 'BitCoin Wallet' by the 'BitCoin Wallet developers', doesn't support BitCoin Cash, so moving BTC to Wallet that supports both. I've dumped my private keys so need to get the BCC to the new wallet.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz so is there any way to get my coins from their current wallet to a different wallet without the standard 'Send BitCoin' which will occur a cost?

Answer (score 1):

If you move the bitcoins now, the bitcoin cash will stay where it is. There are now two separate chains, one for bitcoin and one for bitcoin cash. There is no reason to move the bitcoins. You need to move the bitcoin cash.

To do that you need two things:

1) Some tool that can compose and submit a bitcoin cash transaction.

2) The private key for the account(s) the bitcoin cash are stored in.

Comment: Can I SWEEP or IMPORT the private keys into a different wallet? Both must be moved as they have the same key, so for security I will move BTC first, then the BCC.

Comment: That's fine. I would suggest you first extract all the private keys, then move the BTC (you can use different addresses in the same wallet if you want), then import the private keys into a BCH wallet.

Comment: I've attempted to sweep my private keys into a Coinomi Wallet, but nothing appears.  Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure those were the keys for the addresses where the bitcoins were stored at the time of the fork?

Comment: Yes, I checked on http://blockdozer.com/insight/address/... and https://blockexplorer.com/address/...  The private keys were the same for both, both had the same amount in.  I swept the key for BTC and for BCC and nothing happened.  I've now SENT the BTC to Coinomi Address and that has appeared.  There is nothing for the swept BCC.

Comment: If a BCC explorer says the addresses have bitcoin cash, sweeping them should extract it.